# OAuth Error 1800

Tags: oauth

I have created a connected app and added redirect URI of a Firefox Extension page. Im currently developing this extension. It gives this error:

We can't authorize you because of an OAuth error. For more information, contact your Salesforce administrator.
1800 : There was a problem in setting up your remote access.

When I change URI to a Chrome Extension Page, it works fine. What can be the issue?